# Where would I get a listing of the actual Compute Engine image names?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform

I am trying to do my first provisioning of a Compute Engine instance using Terraform.

One of the parameters needed is the image name being used.  I can see a list of images when manually provisioning an instance through the console, but those are human readable labels for the images (e.g. "CentOS 6", "Ubuntu 16.04 LTS", etc.)  I'm trying to understand where I would get a listing of the actual Compute Engine image names that I would use in the "boot_disk" section of the "resource" directive.

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "Test_CE"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  zone         = "us-east1-b"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "<actual image name goes here>"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CLI `gcloud` will list the images available.

```
gcloud compute images list
```

[Documentation: gcloud compute images list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/list)

The following is the first part of the returned list. Use the string under `NAME` for Terraform.

```
NAME                                                  PROJECT            FAMILY                            DEPRECATED  STATUS
centos-6-v20190213                                    centos-cloud       centos-6                                      READY
centos-7-v20190213                                    centos-cloud       centos-7                                      READY
coreos-alpha-2051-0-0-v20190211                       coreos-cloud       coreos-alpha                                  READY
coreos-beta-2023-3-0-v20190219                        coreos-cloud       coreos-beta                                   READY
coreos-stable-1967-6-0-v20190213                      coreos-cloud       coreos-stable                                 READY
cos-69-10895-138-0                                    cos-cloud          cos-69-lts                                    READY
cos-beta-73-11647-35-0                                cos-cloud          cos-beta                                      READY
cos-dev-74-11758-0-0                                  cos-cloud          cos-dev                                       READY
cos-stable-72-11316-136-0                             cos-cloud          cos-stable                                    READY
debian-9-stretch-v20190213                            debian-cloud       debian-9                                      READY
```

Answer (score 3):

You might find it easier to use the [`google_compute_image` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/datasource_compute_image.html) instead so you can refer to it by it's human readable name there and just use the `self_link` output in your `google_compute_instance` resource.

The `google_compute_image` data source docs provide a good example of this:

```
data "google_compute_image" "my_image" {
  name    = "debian-9"
  project = "debian-cloud"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  # ...

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = data.google_compute_image.my_image.self_link
    }
  }
}
```